# Getting back the id of each item that was placed in each listitem on creation

Tags: android

I am currently designing the message tab on my android app and I got the message activity to display all the user's messages in a listview. Each listitem displays the name of the person who sent the message and the subject of the message. In two hidden textfields I attached the id of the sender and the id of the message. It works properly as I can see it. However I'm trying to implement deletion of the messages after a long press. But what happens is that when I get the background process to run which basically sends to the server the id of the message to be deleted, I realize that for every list item I'm only sending the message id of the first item. If I click on any other item it still shows the first message id. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. This is what I did.

```
public class MyMessages extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> messages = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONParser jsonParser=new JSONParser();
    public static String url_messages="...";
    public static String url_delete_message="...";
    public String theMessage;
    public String mid;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_messages);

        new readMessages().execute();

          ListView lv= getListView();

            registerForContextMenu(lv);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    String message=((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.rMessage)).getText().toString();
                    String name=((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.sentName)).getText().toString();
                    String theirId=((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();
                    Intent in= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReadMessage.class);
                    Bundle extras=new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("name",name);
                    extras.putString("message", message);
                    extras.putString("pid", theirId);
                    in.putExtras(extras);
                    //in.putExtra("picture", picture);
                    startActivityForResult(in, 100);

                }

            });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_messages, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_messages, menu);

    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete_message:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
                //SaveSharedPreference.setUserName(TabExercise.this,"");
                new deleteMessage().execute();
               // Intent intent = new Intent(this, TabExercise.class);
               // intent.putExtra("tab_index","2");
               // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
               // startActivity(intent);

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    class readMessages extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generatNameValuePairb
            List<NameValuePair>param=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","4")); //SaveSharedPreference.getUserId(MyMessages.this)

            JSONObject json=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_messages, "POST", param);
            Log.d("My messages", json.toString());

            try {

                JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("messages");
                Log.d("Messages length",Integer.toString(array.length()));
                //if(array.length()==0)
                    //Log.d("Messages?","No Messages");
                //if(array.length()>0){
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                   // Log.i("name", array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                    JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString("sender_id");
                    String name = c.getString("sender_name");
                    String subject=c.getString("subject");
                    theMessage=c.getString("message");
                    mid=c.getString("message_id");
                    //Log.i("Message Ids", mid);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put("contact_id", id);
                    map.put("sender_name", name);
                    map.put("subject", subject);
                    map.put("message", theMessage);
                    map.put("message_id", mid);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    messages.add(map);
                }
            /*  }else{
                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                    TextView tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nocontacts);
                    tx.setVisibility(0);
                            }
                     });

                }*/
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                return null;
            }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            MyMessages.this, messages,
                            R.layout.list_all_messages, new String[] { "contact_id","sender_name", "subject", "message", "message_id"},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.sentName, R.id.recMessage, R.id.rMessage, R.id.mid });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                }
            });

        }

    }
    class deleteMessage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        String theirName=((TextView) findViewById(R.id.sentName)).getText().toString();
        String messageId=((TextView) findViewById(R.id.mid)).getText().toString();
        String theirId=((TextView) findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generatNameValuePairb
            //List<NameValuePair>param=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","4")); //SaveSharedPreference.getUserId(MyMessages.this)
            //param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mid",messageId));
            //JSONObject json=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_delete_message, "POST", param);
            Log.d("Message Id", messageId );
            Log.d("Their name", theirName );
            Log.d("Their Id", theirId );
            //Log.d("Message status", json.toString());


                return null;
            }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
            //new readNotifications().execute();
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

This is the statement I'm using to get the id of each message on deletion in the AsyncTask

```
String messageId=((TextView) findViewById(R.id.mid)).getText().toString();
```

I feel that, it might be the problem because maybe it's returning just the id of the first listitem.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about where is the problem and is is expected behaviour to get first item for this code.

In documentation You can read about [how to implement context menu on listview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu)

In short to get id of selected list item You have to call method

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
```

inside of `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method

```
info.id
```

contains id of selected item that You can pass to Your asynctask.